# troubleshooting NFS mount loss showing d?

Tags: nfs

Running a cluster where compute nodes NFS mount the `/home` and `/shared` folder from a head node on a LAN - after some amount of time the nodes lose their NFS mount to these folders.  When you log in to the node and do an `ls -l` the `/home` folder shows up as

```
d????????    ??   ??   /home
```

If (as root) I do `umount -l /home; mount /home` it immediately comes back.  As well for any of the 3 or 4 other NFS mounted folders, but then after some amount of time those NFS mounts all go bad again, and then can be restored with `mount` again as described.

**What could cause something  like this, how can this be troubleshooted what files to look into?** `/var/log/messages` shows nothing I can relate to such a problem.

This is under RHEL 7.8 and with `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` and `/etc/nfsmount.conf` roled back to the originally installed files which resulted in NFSv3 happening... or if I use the original RHEL files which have everthing commented out (default settings) results in NFS vers=4.1 happening.  I get this NFS mount loss either way.

Comment: What's the NFS server? Is it healthy (i.e. not crashing and restarting repeatedly)? Is there a firewall device between the server and the clients (its connection tracking might be overloaded and cut off oldest connections)? Does the NFS server assign persistent `fsid`s to the NFS exports/shares? If you are using NFSv3, is the `rpc.statd` service running on both the clients and the server, and accessible from each other?

Answer (score 0):

it was not until I did an `exportfs -f` on the nfs-server that it responded with

*error in config file line 57*.

Within `/etc/nfs.conf` on the nfs server the `[nfsd]` line was commented out with `#` but below I had `rdma=y` not commented out. An obvious error, but doing an `exportfs -arv` and `exportfs -s` responded without error.  And on the nfs client if I did a `mount /home` or any other folder that was exported from the nfs-server (a cluster head node) it worked.  But after some period of time any of those mounts would get lost and then show up as

```
ls -l /

d????????    ?   ?   ?   /home
```